# OR statement in dplyr to calculate depending variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to calculate one single variable depending on a column specification.

```
example.df <- 
data.frame(trial.number = rep(1:10, 
each = 10), GY = sample(-200:200, 
100, replace = T), target.position 
= rep(c("up","down","up","down", 
"up"), each = 20))

test <- example.df %>% 
  group_by(trial.number) %>% 
  summarise(pxpos = 
max(GY[target.position == "up"]) | 
min(GY[target.position == "down"]))
```

So, if the target.position is "up", I want to know the max GY in that trial, when target.position = "down", I want the variable to take the min(GY).

This however doesn't work. I do believe that it is possible though! Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you'll always have the same value in `target.position` in each `trial.numer` we can `group_by` `trial.number` and calculate `max(GY)` if the first value is "up" or else calculate `min`.

```
library(dplyr)

example.df %>%
    group_by(trial.number) %>%
    summarise(pxpos = if_else(target.position[1] == "up", max(GY), min(GY)))



#   trial.number pxpos
#          <int> <dbl>
# 1            1   177
# 2            2   183
# 3            3  -142
# 4            4  -191
# 5            5   143
# 6            6   158
# 7            7  -162
# 8            8  -200
# 9            9   194
#10           10   113
```

---

As pointed out by @Axeman, `if_else` is slow, we can instead replace it with simple `if` `else`

```
example.df %>%
   group_by(trial.number) %>%
   summarise(pxpos = if (target.position[1] == "up")  max(GY) else min(GY))
```

---

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
example.df <- data.frame(trial.number = rep(1:10, each = 10), 
             GY = sample(-200:200,100, replace = T), 
             target.position = rep(c("up","down","up","down", 
                 "up"), each = 20))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I did try if_else myself, but didnt know i had to add the [1] after the target.position. Makes sense, since it evaluates per trial number anyway.

Comment: No need for the slow `if_else`, you can just do `summarise(pxpos = if (first(target.position) == "up") max(GY) else min(GY))`.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks, I was not aware simple `if` `else` is more efficient than `if_else`.

Comment: This surprised me as I always thought that `if_else` would be faster

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` solution, using data provided by @Ronak Shah:

```
example.df %>%
  group_by(trial.number) %>%
  mutate(res = ifelse(target.position == "up", max(GY),
                      ifelse(target.position == "down", min(GY), NA))) %>%
  summarise(res = first(res))

  trial.number   res
          <int> <dbl>
 1            1  177.
 2            2  183.
 3            3 -142.
 4            4 -191.
 5            5  143.
 6            6  158.
 7            7 -162.
 8            8 -200.
 9            9  194.
10           10  113.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
example.df %>%
  group_by(trial.number) %>%
  summarise(pxpos = case_when(first(target.position) == "up" ~ max(GY), 
                   TRUE ~ min(GY)))
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   trial.number pxpos
#            <int> <dbl>
#1            1   177
#2            2   183
#3            3  -142
#4            4  -191
#5            5   143
#6            6   158
#7            7  -162
#8            8  -200
#9            9   194
#10          10   113
```